# How to get date entry values?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkcalendar

I have code as follows:

```
class insert_data(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create calender dropdown menu
        cal_input = DateEntry(
            self,
            width = 12,
            borderwidth = 2,
            year = 2020,
            background = 'blue'
        )
        cal_input.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 5, sticky = 'ew')
```

I am trying to get the value from `cal_input` (date entry widget) and print it on my terminal. However I don't have any idea how to do it. I keep getting errors. I have tried to call class object however I still cannot get the value from the date entry widget. Can anyone give me advice? Any help will be appreciated.

Note: Here is my full code = https://pastebin.com/cYYtBx7b

Comment: Have you tried `cal_input.selection_get()` ?

Comment: Try `cal_input.get_date()`.  See official [document](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/DateEntry.html#tkcalendar.DateEntry.get_date).

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable `entry = StringVar()`

`text=entry.get()` this will store your entry in text

inside `cal_input` use `textvariable=entry`

Modified code is given below

```
class insert_data(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        entry = StringVar()

        # create calender dropdown menu
        cal_input = DateEntry(
            self,
            width = 12,
            borderwidth = 2,
            year = 2020,
            background = 'blue',
            textvariable=entry
        )
        cal_input.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 5, sticky = 'ew')

        print(entry.get())
```